# Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): namespace error : Namespace prefix xhtml on link is not defined in

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to get sitemap data, gzdecode it and create SimpleXMLElement. Got the error "Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): namespace error : Namespace prefix xhtml on link is not defined in".

PHP:

```
$urlget=  $curl->getPage($url);    
$gz= gzdecode($urlget);    
$d2= new SimpleXMLElement($gz);
```

Blueprint of sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
<url>
    <loc></loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-ad" href="" />
</url>
<url>
    <loc></loc>
    <image:image> 
    <image:loc></image:loc>
    <image:title></image:title>
    <image:caption></image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
```

Thanks in advice.

Solution:
Added definition of xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" to the xml files by the provider. As [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop) said xml files are correct now and everthing is good. Thanks [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop).

Comment: If you are right, the cause of error is not me, it is the provider. But not defining a namespace corresponding to this sitemap may cause the error?

Comment: xmlns:xhtml="..." , that is important thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot that did the trick, i ll ask to provider to add the definition, i tried locally and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is telling you that your XML file is incorrectly formatted: there is no definition of what namespace the prefix "xhtml:" refers to.

There should be an attribute somewhere like `xmlns:xhtml="..."`, similar to the one that *is* there for `xmlns:image="..."` which defines the "image:" prefix.

Without that definition, pretty much any parser will reject the document as invalid XML. If possible, you should raise this with whoever is generating the document, and get them to fix it; if not, you'll have to write some hacky code to manipulate it.